# SQL query for update wrong entered values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

i am trying to update the postcode column with the town column as some of the entries in Town column is wrongly entered (user entered post code instead of Town name), so i wrote a query to update postcode column with the postcode values entered in Town column:

```
UPDATE      dbo.ClientLocations
SET         Postcode = cl.Town
FROM        ClientLocations cl INNER JOIN Clients AS c 
            ON cl.ClientId = c.Id
WHERE   (cl.Town IS NOT NULL) AND 
        (cl.Town <> '') AND 
        (cl.Archived IS NULL OR cl.Archived = 0) AND 
        (cl.Postcode IS NULL) AND 
        (c.IsArchived IS NULL OR c.IsArchived = 0)  AND
        (cl.Town <> 'Norwich' AND  cl.Town <> 'Ireland') and 
        cl.ClientId not in (27858,45444)
```

Comment: Whats the question?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are finding that the code doesn't work because all rows are being updated.  You need to use the table alias in the `update`:

```
UPDATE cl
    SET Postcode = cl.Town
    FROM ClientLocations cl INNER JOIN
         Clients AS c ON cl.ClientId = c.Id
    WHERE  (cl.Town IS NOT NULL) AND (cl.Town <> '') AND (cl.Archived IS NULL OR
           cl.Archived = 0) AND (cl.Postcode IS NULL) AND (c.IsArchived IS NULL OR
               c.IsArchived = 0)  AND  (cl.Town <> 'Norwich' AND  cl.Town <> 'Ireland') and cl.ClientId not in (27858, 45444);
```

You may have another question, but you might as well have the `update` do something like what you intend.